# How to simulate a key press when the browser window is minimized?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I work with Selenium Webdriver. How to simulate pressing the right arrow key when the browser window is minimized?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code -

```
body = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Comment: which element? I don't have any. The program opens a browser and then it should simply press the keyboard button.

Comment: Edited my ans. please take a look and mark it as answer if it solve problem.

Comment: is it possible to do without any "find_element_by"? Through "ActionChains" and "perform()" or something?